# Deleting duplicates keeping the minimum ID

Tags: sql, oracle11g, duplicates

I have a persons table with duplicate person inserted with different id. I want to delete the person with duplicate names keeping only the person with the minimum ID.
for e.G The record for Absalon with ID 18398 should remain and all the other duplicates are deleted.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 15):

```sql
DELETE FROM persons WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM persons GROUP BY name)
```

Comment: I get an error with mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52: `mysql> delete from domain_map where id not in (select min(id) from domain_map group by domain);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'domain_map' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @abatie Please make a new question tagged with `mysql`, since this question was not about mysql and every SQL dialect is different.

Comment: @abatie Or you may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471463/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-sql-table-based-on-multiple-fields

Comment: I was not asking a question - I was pointing out that the answer doesn't work, at the very least not in this particular version of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH duplicatable As
( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY name, ORDER BY id ASC ) as row_number FROM table_name
)
SELECT * FROM duplicatable WHERE row_number > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for mysql

```
DELETE tb2<br>
FROM persons as tb1, persons as tb2<br>
WHERE (tb1.name=tb2.name AND tb1.id<tb2.id)
```