# How to remove duplicates from an entity in phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in which a step with the field name StepID and the id 113 can be found 3 times in an entity called PlaceID. Is there a way to leave only one step with the id 113 in each of my entities by running a query? This is what I want to remove http://prntscr.com/ebi9y3 .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates in SQL table based on multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471463/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-sql-table-based-on-multiple-fields)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)